# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: (IntelliJ idea)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm getting the above error when I try to execute the following command.

```
java -cp target/helloHBase-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar HBaseIA.TwitBase.UsersTool add TheRealMT "Mark Twain" samuel@clemens.org abc123
```

I'm using IntelliJIdea IDE and all my maven '`clean`', '`install`' and '`package`' commands give "**`Build Success`**" message.

The directory structure of the project is provided below. I've already imported the hbase jar files to my project as external libraries in IntelliJ.

[image]

Complete error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HTablePool
        at HBaseIA.TwitBase.UsersTool.main(UsersTool.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTablePool
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 1 more
```

`pom.xml` provided below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>helloHBase</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
            <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>  
</project>
```

Comment: Are the hbase jar files compiled as part of the helloHBase-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar?

Comment: If you're running java directly, you also have to setup you classpath.  Which, can be tedious if you have to do it by hand.  If you use the integrated intellij run/debug command, it will setup your classpath for you.

Comment: Hi @hooknc I want to execute the jar file I created from 'mvn package' command, with the above command I mentioned.

Comment: @AK47, I already imported hbase-client library as an external library to IntelliJ and included it in the pom.xml

Comment: @CoolCK yep it's imported within IntelliJ, but you're running it on the cmd line. Is it packaged within the jar?

Comment: @AK47 , I'm newbie to maven. How may I know if it is packaged ? I already executed mvn clean, mvn build and mvn package commands. Do I have to separately include the hbase jar file in the new jar file ?

Comment: @SiKing , would you mind share how should I update my pom.xml . I believe I have to add build tags (and others) to my pom.xml according to the post.

Comment: `maven package` doesn't create an executable jar file.  If you're making a jar, it just takes your code and then packages it up in a jar file.  This means that you will have to set you classpath when running your application.  There are ways of creating an executable jar file, but you'll need to use a Spring maven plugin:  https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven